# Public Transportation, cheapest route from Newburgh, to Potsdam, NY?

Tags: budget, public-transport, routes, new-york-state

I lack the ability to drive and need to leave Newburgh, New York and travel to Potsdam, New York on a personal trip. How can I do this more effectively than traveling to New York city port authority( ~20$) and then taking a 10 hour bus to Potsdam, New York(84$)?

By effective, I guess I mean a good combination of price and time.

Please be as detailed as possible, I am a shut in and traveling often confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The invaluable Rome2Rio has a [bus routing](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Newburgh/Potsdam-NY-USA) that is still 10+ hours, but does not backtrack to NYC. The first transfer point is Binghamton.

Comment: R2R Gives the right idea just the wrong schedules.  The New York/Pine Hill Trailways can be taken from Binghamton directly to Potsdam but there are only 2 buses that stop in that Village.  Plus Coach USA only has 3 buses from Newburgh to Binghamton, so your < 10 hour ride can turn into an overnight nightmare, so use NYC as your connecting point it's a lot easier.

Comment: R2R also had a routing using the train, then picking up the last bus. Preferring train to bus, I'd consider that but it is more expensive.

Comment: Getting there by bus looks so complicated and potentially time consuming that if I were doing this I'd give up, take the train to Albany, and fly up there.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think I'd sign up for driver's ed.

Comment: I think I'll just go to nyc and then take the greyhound, if its 10 hours either way id rather go the familar route. Thanks